# Java initializing instance variables - IDE shows field names?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In the below screenshot containing code for adding elements to a `List`, the instance variables are being initialized in a way I haven't come across before. I have tried to do the same in eclipse but was unable to replicate it. I understand initializing variables via constructor in this way -

```
new Potus("Donald","Trump",2016,"Republican")
```

but this way -

`new Potus(firstName:"Donald",lastName:"Trump",electionYear:2016,party:"Republican")`

is something new for me. I do not have the source code as well as its not available for download. Can you please let me know which is the topic it comes under or provide me any reference. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: That’s just something IntelliJ does to make reading easier. It isn’t valid syntax.

Comment: To add to Logan’s comment, it’s simply IntelliJ telling you how a literal maps to a parameter.

Comment: Oh ok understood thank you for the information. But if such features are added which isn't valid it reduces readability for other users right..

Comment: Not necessarily. Other readers are using *their* own IDE. If these readers do not want to see these "hints", they can disable them. Again: this is something that the IDE is showing to the reader. It is **not** in the source code, it is just a VISUAL artefact added by the IDE to actually make it easier to understand what is going on!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its **just for you to view and sugarcoating done by IntelliJ**. This is **not** a valid java syntax.

Try to view this file from some text editor and you'll see the actual code.

It'll only have code like:

```
new Potus("Barak","Obama",2012,"Democratic")
```

***and not like:***

```
new Potus(firstName:"Donald",lastName:"Trump",electionYear:2016,party:"Republican")
```

**IntelliJ** is just doing its best to guide us not to err.

Answer (score 2):

This is a `parameter/argument` name `suggestion/hint` in IntelliJ Idea and it has no relation with the `Java` syntax. You can disable it from `Settings | Editor | General | Appearance`. However, I find it useful.